# Update SeekBar in Fragment with value from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have an app with action bar. It has a "Main" fragment and a "Preferences" fragment.

```
    final Main main = new Main();
    final Preferences preferences = new Preferences();
    drawer.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Fragment fragment= null;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = main;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = preferences;
                    break;
            }
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment)
                .commit();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        });
```

The "Preferences" fragment has a seekBar that is updated with a value from SharedPreferences. This is the relevant code that makes this within the "Preferences" fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    container.removeAllViews();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preferences, container, false);

    fontSizeBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.fontSizeBar);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Preferences.this.getActivity().getBaseContext());
    final int fontSize = preferences.getInt("fontSize", 10);


    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fontSizeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                    Log.v("Progress changed", "Font size: " + progress);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    Log.v("Start touching", "Font size: " + seekBar.getProgress());
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.v("Stop touching", "Font size: " + seekBar.getProgress());
                }

            });
            fontSizeBar.setMax(10);
            fontSizeBar.setProgress(fontSize);
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.preferences, container, false);

}
```

The method onProgressChanged() is called, because I can see the output "Progress changed", "Font size: 10" in LogCat, but the SeekBar is not visually updated. Additionally,the SeekBar does not responds to the methods onStartTrackingTouch() and onStopTrackingTouch().

I will appreciate any information that could shed some light about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing everything right, inflating the views and setting up the logic but at the end you do this:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.preferences, container, false);
```

which will return a **newly** inflated layout(so you drop everything you previously done). Instead you need to return the `view` which you previously inflated:

```
return view;
```